# Discord.py on_raw_reaction_add() - not adding role to member

Tags: python, discord.py

I am coding a bot that will assign roles based on reacting with an emoji.  I have double checked my syntax, discord.py documentation, and in cross referencing a couple of YouTube videos it seems everything checks out, but to this day the bot will not add a role to a member.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == MESSAGE:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        print(MESSAGE)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'test':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='TestRole')
            print("TestRole")
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("Added role to user . . .")
            else:
                print("User not found . . .")
        else:
            print("Role not found . . .")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you setup your [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html). Also, use `guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)` to get the guild, `member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)` to get the member, and `role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='TestRole')` to get the role. Here is a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYyDZXktojI&t=7s) on how to setup a role reaction bot with latest discord.py. When you use `if message_id == MESSAGE:` it isn't going to do anything because you need to instead put the actual integer ID of your role reaction message there instead. This should work after you setup intents:

```
from discord.utils import get
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 1234567890:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)        
        # this wouldn't do anything because MESSAGE is not defined
        print(MESSAGE)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'test':
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='TestRole')
            print("TestRole")
        else:
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
            if member is not None:
                await payload.member.add_roles(role)
                print(f"Added role to {member}")
            else:
                print("User not found . . .")
        else:
            print("Role not found . . .")
```

Comment: I will try that.  The reason I have the MEMBER variable is because I set up a .env file to store the message ID.  Do you think that the message ID isn't being successfully passed?

Comment: Then MESSAGE is most likely fine, but you aren't getting an error so try the edits I suggested and see what happens. You could just put the message ID in and see if it fixes it as well.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason your recommendations were breaking my code.  I reverted back to my original changes.  Now getting errors.  Is it against Stack Overflow to ask your assistance via Discord?

Comment: I don't think so, my discord server is [here](https://discord.gg/WYcxrDM).

Comment: For whatever reason it still wasn't working with what you recommended, but... what did get it to work was replacing MESSAGE = os.getenv("MESSAGE") to MESSAGE_ID = int(os.getenv("MESSAGE_ID")) in my original code set. I was pulling the MESSAGE_ID from the .env file and for whatever reason discord.py really wanted to handle 'MESSAGE_ID' as an integer.

Thanks for your help though.